# Convert a JavaScript import to an array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node-modules, ng-modules

I have a NPM package that I need to load most of the modules for. I can do the import statement like this:

`import * as primeng from 'primeng/primeng';`

But in my [@NgModule](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html) Angular declaration, I need to explicitly list out every single element in the imports section:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [

    BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule,

    // primeNG
    primeng.ButtonModule, primeng.ChipsModule, primeng.ContextMenuModule, primeng.DataTableModule,
    primeng.DialogModule, primeng.DropdownModule, primeng.EditorModule, primeng.FieldsetModule,
    primeng.GMapModule, primeng.GrowlModule, primeng.InputSwitchModule, primeng.InputTextModule, 
    primeng.PanelMenuModule, primeng.PanelModule, primeng.SharedModule, primeng.SpinnerModule, primeng.TreeModule

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Is there any way to instead use something like `primeng.keys()` (which doesn't work) to my imports section of the NgModule?

Comment: Given that it's a decorator,  `Object.values(primeng)` should work, no?

Comment: ``Object.values(primeng)`` gives me back the typescript error ``Property 'values' does not exist on type 'ArrayConstructor'``

Comment: @Bergi's comment should be marked as the answer - it worked for me! I needed to convert `import * as Foo from './foo'` into an array of  each exported const from './foo'. `Object.values(Foo)` did the trick.

Comment: Object.values didn't work for angular 9.